# mongoose find() function does not return the whole object, skips the empty field

Tags: mongoose

I am using mongoose find() to find a particular attribute that looks across various attributes, like this

```
 exports.isPhoneAlreadyExists = (req, res) => {

  var searchedPhone = req.params.phone;

 var searchOnPhoneWithOr = [{ 'phone1': searchedPhone }, { 'phone2': searchedPhone }, { 'phone3': searchedPhone }, { 'phone4': searchedPhone }, { 'phone5': searchedPhone }];
  contact.find({ $or: searchOnPhoneWithOr }, {}, function (err, resp) {
    if (err) {

        res.send(err);
    }

    res.json(resp);
});
};
```

it does not returns me the whole object, it only returns those attributes which are non empty, i want to get the whole object along with empty attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB does by default not save empty objects to the DB. To avoid this behaviour, you can set the "minimize" flag in the collection option to "false".

I am not quite sure if this also applies to "primitive" values like strings or numbers, but if you only work with objects, you should be fine.

Check this for more info: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#minimize